# Weblogic ActiveDirectory get full user name instead of id of logged in user

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have managed to configure ActiveDirectory authenticator on weblogic, and our web application successfully authenticates AD users now, the issue I have is I am not able to get logged in user's full name. Is it possible?

I am getting just userId from both http request's getUserPrincipal and getRemoteUser methods. thanks.

Comment: I know it's possible if you write your own LDAP/AD provider. Have you looked into a custom solution? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13707/atn.htm#SECMG173

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we are for now just trying to work with default AD authenticator weblogic provides, if we don't find a solution we may have to consider other options